# How to implement ng2-tree for dynamically loading folder and file recursively

Tags: angular

Hi I am using angular 5 and Ng2-tree for Creating Tree and my case is to load sub child on the expand event of each node. So i found loadChildren of TreeModel but its not working when i using http request inside it.

Here i my Implementation.

```
var jsonArray: any;

this.hdfsService.getService(this.hdfsService.getHdfsPonds("/")).then(result => {
  jsonArray = result.fileStatus.filter(function (i) {
    return i.type === "DIRECTORY";
  });
  for (let jsonVal of jsonArray) {
    let tree1: TreeModel = {
      value: jsonVal.name,
      name: jsonVal.path,
      settings: { isCollapsedOnInit: false },
      loadChildren:(callback) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log("=================================executed")
          callback(this.loadChild(jsonVal.path));
        }, 5000);
      }
    };
    this.hdfsPondArray.push(tree1);
    this.onNodeCreated(this.formTOAddNewPond.value.path);
    this.formTOAddNewPond.reset();
    this.showDialog = false;
  }
});
```

and my childLoad method

```
loadChild(path) {
var childJsonArray: any;
var childrens: TreeModel[] = [];
var testArray: any[] = [];
this.hdfsService.extractArray("/"+path).subscribe((json: any) => {
  childJsonArray = json.fileStatus;
  for (let json of childJsonArray) {
    testArray.push({value:json.name})
  }
});
console.log("=========================================================================================");
console.log(testArray);
return testArray
```

}

Another situation is my children nodes can further call its sub child so is it possible with Ng2-tree , And why my code not showing while its fetching folders correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it, by calling method before callback and then put call back in setTimeout(); Something like this.

```
loadChildren: (callback) => {
        var childrens: TreeModel[] = this.loadChild(jsonVal.path)
        setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("=================================executed")
        callback(childrens);
        }, 300);
      }
```

if there's any best practice than please share.